# devise + omniauth-google-oauth2 calling errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, oauth-2.0, omniauth

Hi I am trying to integrate devise and omniauth login on my app. I am trying with omniauth-google-oauth2 and I follow the instrunctions on this tutorial https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3A-Overview

I do it all but I keep getting a google error message

```
Error: invalid_request
Missing required parameter: client_id
Learn more
Request Details
response_type=code
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback
access_type=offline
approval_prompt=
state=50665ea3f96dc12e2189e93e1bc40592fc35ce5167d462e0
client_id=
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Check that you correctly set the APP_ID in `devise.rb` and restarted your server (`config.omniauth :google_oauth2, "APP_ID", "APP_SECRET", { access_type: "offline", approval_prompt: "" }`

Comment: Should i be putting the actual the client id and access id on devise.rb or where should I have them? Sorry I'm kinda new to Rails

Comment: Go to https://code.google.com/apis/console/ to create an app and get your APP_ID and APP_SECRET values, as explained in the "Google OAuth2 example" of the link in your question.

You will also need to install this Gem https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2

Watch these 2 railscast, you may find some help: http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1;

Comment: Thanks @Baldrick I got it now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Baldrick's answer helped me solve it.

Make sure that

```
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, "APP_ID", "APP_SECRET", { access_type: "offline", approval_prompt: "" }
```

is correctly set